# GPS distance calculation may not be accurate

Tags: java, c#, android

Im writing an Android app in java to calculate distance traveled using the GPS.

The app sends the GPS coordinates to the server every 4 seconds which saves all the points in a big array. At the end of the trip the server calculates the total distance by adding up the distance between each of the individual points.

The problem is the final distance is always a little less than the real distance, so anybody using my app will complain that the distance is always wrong!

Maybe the reason why the distance is always less is that the distance between two points taken 4 seconds apart while driving, is always less than the real distance especially if the driver takes a lot of curves and turns.

The only way i know to improve this is by sending the GPS position more often to the server, but this will use more data, pissing off the user again!

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Here is the code that calculates the distance between two points using great circle calculation in c#

```
    public static double DistanceTo(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, char unit = 'M')
    {
        double rlat1 = Math.PI * lat1 / 180;
        double rlat2 = Math.PI * lat2 / 180;
        double theta = lon1 - lon2;
        double rtheta = Math.PI * theta / 180;
        double dist = Math.Sin(rlat1) * Math.Sin(rlat2) + Math.Cos(rlat1) * Math.Cos(rlat2) * Math.Cos(rtheta);
        dist = Math.Acos(dist);
        dist = dist * 180 / Math.PI;
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;

        switch (unit) {
            case 'K': //Kilometers -> default
                return dist * 1.609344;
            case 'N': //Nautical Miles 
                return dist * 0.8684;
            case 'M': //Miles
                return dist;
        }

        return dist;
    }
```

Comment: I think the problem is actualy non-existent. If you get the position every 4 seconds or so and the movement is more or less linear, you should not get any significant deviation.

Comment: [Extrapolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation)

Comment: im getting 3% error, so I fake it by just adding 3% more to the calculated distance